# Assembly x86/C -Recursive Binomial Coefficient Segfault/printing pascals triangle

Tags: c, recursion, assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64

I've written some code (main in c, subprogram in assembly x86) to calculate all the binomial coefficients recursively and print out all the binomial coefficients with n=10, restricted by m<=n.

So basically I'm trying to output a pascals triangle for n=10. (without the whole format of a triangle)

My problem is that I'm getting a segfault on compile and I'm having trouble figuring out how to print the individual values generated by the recursive function.

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here's the main program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int result,m,n,i;
unsigned int binom(int,int);
int main(){

n=10;


for (i=0; i<n+1;i++){
printf("i=%d | %d \n", i, binom(n,i) );
}

return;


}
```

And the recursive sub program:

```
    .text
    .globl  binom

binom: 
    mov     $0x00, %edx     #for difference calculation
    cmp     %edi, %esi          #m=n?
    je      equalorzero         #jump to equalorzero for returning of value 1
    cmp     $0x00, %esi         #m=0?
    je      equalorzero     
    cmp     $0x01, %esi         #m=1?

    mov     %esi,%edx
    sub     %edi, %edx
    cmp     $0x01, %edx         # n-m = 1 ?
    je      oneoronedifference  

    jmp     otherwise

equalorzero:
    add     $1, %eax            #return 1
    ret 

oneoronedifference:
    add     %edi, %eax          #return n
    ret

otherwise:
    sub     $1, %edi            #binom(n-1,m) 
    call    binom       
    sub     $1, %esi            #binom(n-1,m-1)
    call    binom
```

This is what gcc is giving me

```
./runtimes
i=0 | 12 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: After the label `otherwise:` you have 4 lines but then there is nothing to end the code. Is there a missing `ret`? After the last `call binom` the CPU will continue to execute what ever semi random data is in memory and will segfault, hang, or generally act incorrectly. You should run your code in a debugger.

Comment: My understanding was that when the binom is called it'll recurse into equalorzero or oneoronedifference, which contain ret in them. - I'll add a ret in there to stop it from doing that.

Comment: This didn't fix the segfault - maybe it fixed another though, I'm sure I needed that ret at the end to prevent what you mentioned

Comment: you should try out gdb...

Comment: @Egyptian_Coder please take some time to read this comment. It is time for you to learn how to use a debugger. You have currently asked 8 questions in your SO career and they **all are about debugging**. If you'd learned to use gdb after the first one you'd be proficient by now. You code has a lot of beginner mistakes (Wrong register usage, spurious instructions, missing conditions) easy fixed by a quick debugging, and this is constant throughout  all your questions. I'm voting to close this question and I hope to see a more mature behavior on your side henceforth.

Answer (score 1):

The two major issues with your assembly code are: 1) you niether add nor return the sum of the two recursive calls; 2) you don't save your locals on the stack so they are wiped out by the recursive calls -- you're using the wrong values once you return from the calls.  Here's my rework of your code, some of the changes are due to my writing this under OSX:

The recursive sub program:

```
    .text
    .globl  _binom

_binom:
    pushq   %rbp                 # allocate space on stack for locals
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $24, %rsp

    cmpl    %edi, %esi           # m == n ?
    je      equalorzero          # jump to equalorzero for returning of value 1
    cmpl    $0, %esi             # m == 0 ?
    je      equalorzero     

    movl    %esi, %edx
    subl    %edi, %edx
    cmpl    $1, %edx             # n - m == 1 ?
    je      oneoronedifference  

    subl    $1, %edi             # binom(n - 1, m) 
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
    callq   _binom

    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)      # save result to stack

    movl    -4(%rbp), %edi
    movl    -8(%rbp), %esi
    subl    $1, %esi             # binom(n - 1, m - 1)
    callq   _binom

    addl    -12(%rbp), %eax      # add results of the two recursive calls
    addq    $24, %rsp            # release locals space on stack
    popq    %rbp
    retq

equalorzero:
    movl    $1, %eax             # return 1
    addq    $24, %rsp            # release locals space on stack
    popq    %rbp
    retq

oneoronedifference:
    movl    %edi, %eax           # return n
    addq    $24, %rsp            # release locals space on stack
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

The main program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned int binom(int, int);

int main() {

    int n = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("i=%d | %d\n", i, binom(n, i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the results:

```
i=0 | 1
i=1 | 10
i=2 | 45
i=3 | 120
i=4 | 210
i=5 | 252
i=6 | 210
i=7 | 120
i=8 | 45
i=9 | 10
i=10 | 1
```